# Required @SWG\Info() not found

Tags: php, swagger, laravel-5.1

I'm pretty new to using Swagger. Since my project is with Laravel, I use Swaggerevel to document my API. During I tried to generate as follows,

```
./vendor/bin/swagger app/ -o storage/docs/api-docs.json
```

It shows that

```
[INFO] Required @SWG\Info() not found

    get /api/resource.json
-----------------------
1 operations documented
-----------------------
Written to /home/admin/api/gevme-api/storage/docs/api-docs.json
```

When I tried to access, It `localhost:8000/docs`, It properly show json api which I generated. But when I tried to access `localhost:8000/api-docs`, the same error message show again.

```
ErrorException in Logger.php line 38:
Required @SWG\Info() not found
in Logger.php line 38
at HandleExceptions->handleError('1024', 'Required @SWG\Info() not found', '/home/admin/api/gevme-api/vendor/zircote/swagger-php/src/Logger.php', '38', array('entry' => 'Required @SWG\Info() not found', 'type' => '1024'))
at trigger_error('Required @SWG\Info() not found', '1024') in Logger.php line 38
at Logger->Swagger\{closure}('Required @SWG\Info() not found', '1024')
at call_user_func(object(Closure), 'Required @SWG\Info() not found', '1024') in Logger.php line 68
at Logger::notice('Required @SWG\Info() not found') in AbstractAnnotation.php line 365
at AbstractAnnotation->validate() in Analysis.php line 284
at Analysis->validate() in functions.php line 46
at Swagger\scan('/home/admin/api/gevme-api/modules/Api', array('exclude' => array('/home/admin/api/gevme-api/storage', '/home/admin/api/gevme-api/tests', '/home/admin/api/gevme-api/resources/views', '/home/admin/api/gevme-api/config', '/home/admin/api/gevme-api/vendor'))) in routes.php line 39
at SwaggervelServiceProvider->{closure}()
at call_user_func_array(object(Closure), array()) in Route.php line 155
at Route->runCallable(object(Request)) in Route.php line 130
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 704
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 706
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 671
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 631
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 236
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in OAuthExceptionHandlerMiddleware.php line 36
at OAuthExceptionHandlerMiddleware->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(OAuthExceptionHandlerMiddleware), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 62
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 122
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 87
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
at require_once('/home/admin/api/gevme-api/public/index.php') in server.php line 21
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The problem is - you're missing the `@SWG\Info` block. 
It's a block which tells swagger some most common information about your API.

I usually put this in a separate controller which is rendering swagger JSON. 
Here's an example:

```
/**
 * @SWG\Swagger(
 *     schemes={"http","https"},
 *     host="api.host.com",
 *     basePath="/",
 *     @SWG\Info(
 *         version="1.0.0",
 *         title="This is my website cool API",
 *         description="Api description...",
 *         termsOfService="",
 *         @SWG\Contact(
 *             email="contact@mysite.com"
 *         ),
 *         @SWG\License(
 *             name="Private License",
 *             url="URL to the license"
 *         )
 *     ),
 *     @SWG\ExternalDocumentation(
 *         description="Find out more about my website",
 *         url="http..."
 *     )
 * )
 */

class SwaggerController extends...
```

Comment: i have got the same error but with Lumen framework using DarkaOnLine/SwaggerLume.
where can i find this file to edit it ?

Comment: Wherever you place your Swagger documentation. You usually need to create it manually. I don't know about Lumen.

Comment: @AhmedZelfani did you find how did you fix this ?

Comment: @AhmedZelfani @user269867 
You can create a simple controller like Mathew does above in your `app/Http/Controllers` directory.

Answer (score 0):

If this happens to you, and you have the Swagger definition in the controller etc but still aren't seeing the comments make sure you don't have the following settings in your opcache configuration:

```
opcache.save_comments=1
opcache.load_comments=1
```

The settings above remove and not-load the docblox needed for swagger to create the documentation.

Comment: what? are you sure?

Answer (score 0):

For Laravel 5.6 I launched

```
composer require darkaonline/l5-swagger:5.6
```

and quietly installed version 5.6.0 (which was linked to zircote/swagger-php version **TWO**), and I got subj error having `@OA\Info` block in Controller even.

When I runned

```
composer require darkaonline/l5-swagger:5.6.9
```

and increased version of  zircote/swagger-php to

```
composer require zircote/swagger-php:3.0.2
```

my problem was solved